# Meteor/React Router: error message "there is no route defined"

Tags: reactjs, meteor, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

Unfortunately, I can't get React Router to work in my custom meteor boilerplate and I really can't figure out why. Here's all the files that could potentially be relevant to the problem:

\client\main.js:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { renderRoutes } from '../imports/startup/client/routes.jsx';

Meteor.startup(() => {
  render(renderRoutes(), document.getElementById('app'));
});
```

\imports\startup\client\routes.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

// route components
import App from '../../ui/App.jsx';

export const renderRoutes = () => (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <Route path="/" component={App} />
    </div>
  </Router>
);
```

\imports\ui\App.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { withTracker } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <h1>Hey!</h1>
    );
  }
}

export default withTracker(() => {
  return {
  };
})(App);
```

Any idea why the error message might occur? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what version of meteor and react you are using but tha's how i did it on the last project i had.

Try this changes:

```
import {Router, Route, browserHistory} from 'react-router';

export const renderRoutes = () => (
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <div>
      <Route path="/" component={App} />
    </div>
  </Router>
);
```

Comment: Hm, that's how I had it before (took it from an older project). But it didn't work, so I figured that they changed some things in React router v4. Which is also what it says in the React router documentation which I find not very helpful in general. So, I guess I will just use Flow Router then. ;-)